# Machine based group policy to change display setting

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, display

How to change display using computer group policy?

Answer (score 3):

You don't - as such. The difference between a machine policy and a user policy is the place where those registry are - either in the machine registry or the user registry. If a piece of software (Or in this case Windows) only looks for one or the other, then that's that.

However, you can still do what you need. Group Policy supports Loopback Policy Processing which allows the application of User Policies on a machine by machine basis.

You will NEED to do some reading on this as Loopback can be a bit confusing and has some requirements, especially around the security filtering.

The short story is that you'll configure Loopback - Merge mode on the computer side and in the same OU (I.e., the computer OU) you'll then configure your required display settings.

When a user logs onto that machine, the user based policies for that OU will then be applied, along with their normal user OU policies.